# create limit character for mysql user in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I have created a bash script to create a MySQL database and user.

The username is my domain with dots replaced by `_` (example_com).  But the user field length limit is 16 characters.

Ex:

```
PASS="$(openssl rand -base64 12)"
DBNAME=${DOMAIN//[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_}

mysql -uroot -p${rootpasswd} -e "CREATE DATABASE ${DBNAME} /*\!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;"
mysql -uroot -p${rootpasswd} -e "CREATE USER '${DBNAME}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS';"
mysql -uroot -p${rootpasswd} -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DBNAME}.* TO '${DBNAME}'@'localhost';"
mysql -uroot -p${rootpasswd} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

How can I ensure the 16 characters limit is respected before sending the query to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cut the DBNAME value to the max desired length like this:

```
SHORT_DBNAME=${DBNAME:0:16}
```

Ex:

```
DBNAME=0123456789abcdefghijklmnop
SHORT_DBNAME=${DBNAME:0:16}
echo $SHORT_DBNAME
```

Will return `0123456789abcdef`

Now you have to be careful that the first 16 chars combination is unique.  If the difference is past the 16th character, if you try to create two users, names will be the same.

Comment: Really, unaccepted 2 years after it was accepted?